Play only one audio at once
I have aa list of podcast links using the audio tag, they all play when I click on the play button but i want the first to pause when i play another
<div class="podcast-container">
    <audio controls src="https://assets.mixkit.co/music/preview/mixkit-tech-house-vibes-130.mp3"></audio>
    <audio controls src="https://assets.mixkit.co/music/preview/mixkit-hazy-after-hours-132.mp3"></audio>
    <audio controls src="https://assets.mixkit.co/music/preview/mixkit-tech-house-vibes-130.mp3"></audio>
</div>

I tried the below code to pause the audio but then it doesn't play at all. Please help
  const tracks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('audio'));
   tracks.forEach(function (track) {
      track.addEventListener('play', (event) => {
         tracks.forEach(function (track) {
             track.pause();
         })
      })
   })


The problem with your code is that, you are not checking the current audio playing, passing a pause() will pause all the audio. You need to use the event to check the current audio like this, if the track is not equal to the present one then pause it.
if (track !== event.target) track.pause();

overall code should look the below.
   const tracks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('audio'));
    tracks.forEach(function (track) {
    track.addEventListener('play', (event) => {
     tracks.forEach(function (track) {
        if (track !== event.target) track.pause();
     })
    })
   })

